# Prevent screen blur in React Native Navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6

React Navigation library  supply me the `blur` event, that trigs when the focused screen is going to be unfocused. Great.

But what if I need to prevent the blur action itself by stopping the user to go away from this screen? The docs only mentions the 'beforeRemove' event, that is something else.

Is there a way to prevent a user to go away from a screen using the screen component logic?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, blur event's callback function must navigate to this page

Comment: that's an obviuos statement

Comment: If you add this in useEffect, it navigates thisPage, when it is blur

`navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      navigation.navigate(thisPage);
});`